# Prompt string 1 length

Tags: prompt, bash

I have created a nice prompt string that allows me to track the current working directory. However I have made a simple mistake. I am not using brackets correctly "[" and "]" and it is causes bash to misrepresent the number of characters in the prompt which prevents correct wrapping of long commands.

```
export PS1="\[\033[0;34m\]\w \033[0;30m\]\]\$ "
```

I have tried [this helpful example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24358/how-do-i-get-long-command-lines-to-wrap-to-the-next-line) but am not sure what to fix.

Comment: Each part of the prompt that has length 0 should be wrapped in `\[...\]`.

Comment: Does the output of \w count as length 0?

Comment: `\w` is expanded by `bash` internally, so it knows how to compute the length of the resulting string. It does not need to be enclosed. Only characters like the escape sequences which the *terminal* reduces to a 0-length string need to be enclosed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quote with right escaping like this:

```
export PS1='[\[\033[0;34m\]\w\[\033[0;30m\]]$ '
```